# Map 2 spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2008

I have two spreadsheet.

Both spredsheets have an email field. Spreadsheet 1 has 400 email fields and the other has 1000 email fields. The 400 emails are in the 1000 email spreadsheet. The 1000 email spreadsheet has more columns of data that the 400 email spreadsheet does not have, I am trying to add these other columns to the 400 email spreadsheet. There are 6 columns I am looking to add.

My question is, is there away to map these spreadsheets based on email address, so I can get the other columns in the 400 email spreadsheet?

I am using Excel 2008 for Mac.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is the information static or does it change?  Are you looking for a one-time copying of information or linking the two spreadsheets?

Comment: Man! Sounds like vlookup is in order!